# Does USB Internet option require root access?

Tags: usb, 4.2-jelly-bean, reverse-tether

Hi I want to reverse tether from PC, OS Win 8.1 to android device but is it required root?
In Activity in Local Area Connection Status (Local Area Connection is my Remote NDIS...) I get increased Sent values but this increase is very slow(i.e 168 bytes and after few seconds 210 bytes, and another secs 252 bytes) and not fluent, Received values increase proper and relatively faster than Sent values

I have on the phone 'USB internet active' notification, on PC
I have in Connection section in General

**IPv4 Connectivity**: 'No network access'

the same with IPv6

**Media State**: Enabled

**Duration**: (8 minutes and is increasing)

**Speed**: 425.9 Mbps

Ethernet is my PC connection with speed 100 Mbps but I live in dorm and really I have lower speed
Phone Model: Quantum 350

I have tried enable sharing tab

and when I launch Opera mini go to some website i.e www.google.com then browser loads and loads and after few minutes I get confirm dialog with info that cannot connect but during the 39 minutes my phone received 395,000 bytes and increasing now (during 45 minutes) I have 460,000 and increasing

Answer (score 0):

ReverseTethering does not require a rooted device. Depending on your device, it might come with a preinstalled reverse tethering option. Unfortunately, this preinstalled solution is only included in very few devices.

I am the developer of ReverseTethering NoRoot, an app that brings reverse tethering to any Android device running Android 4.0 or newer. No root required. All major host OSs are supported. The app is available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free).